# Testing-Library React don't trigger click after an async

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write a test in Jest.
When the `fireEvent.click` comes after an async `it` it doesn't trigger the function.

This is the exact case where few lines of code are better than hundreds of words that describes the issue. In the snippet below, the second and third test are exactly the same (copy-and-pasted) except for the name of the test itself of course.

```js
import {render, screen, waitFor, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';

const Component = ({asyncClick, syncClick}) => {
    function onClick(){
        console.log('clicked');
        syncClick();
        setTimeout(() => {
            asyncClick();
        }, 50);
    }
    return <div data-testid="toBeClick" onClick={onClick}>

    </div>;
}

describe('a test', function(){
    it('element exists', function(){
        render(<Component/>);
        let el = screen.getByTestId('toBeClick');
        expect(el).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('element Click', async function(){
        let syncClick = jest.fn();
        let asyncClick = jest.fn();
        render(<Component asyncClick={asyncClick} syncClick={syncClick} />);
        let el = screen.getByTestId('toBeClick');
        fireEvent.click(el);
        expect(syncClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(asyncClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });

    });

    it('element Click / 2', async function(){
        let syncClick = jest.fn();
        let asyncClick = jest.fn();
        render(<Component asyncClick={asyncClick} syncClick={syncClick} />);
        let el = screen.getByTestId('toBeClick');
        fireEvent.click(el);
        expect(syncClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(asyncClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });

    });

})
```

The second test pass. The third test fails. Why?

As a side note, removing `async/await` and the `waitFor` from the second test, even the third test starts to pass.

-- UPDATE
Looks like the failure is due to an import in jest-setup.js:

```
require('ionic/js/ionic.js');
```

I'm importing Ionic v1 and it breaks the tests.

Comment: Your code looks ok for me. I didn't get any fail tests while running it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap async actions that trigger something in [act](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#act).

> ```
> act(() => {
>   fireEvent.click()
> });
> ```

Can try to use [jest.useFakeTimers() and jest.runAllTimers()](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks).

In begin of test **jest.useFakeTimers()** and after click dispatched  **jest.runAllTimers()**

If nothing works can try

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
```